# VB.NET Syntax Highlighting inside of text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've just started looking at some examples of syntax highlighting in VB.NET, and it's working pretty decently. However, is there any way to check for certain text inside of another text? For example, if I want `" "` to be highlighted orange, that works fine. But what If I wanted any text inside of `" "` to be blue? Is there any way to check for text only inside that? My current code (not mine, pulled from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afee34bc-25ab-405c-ab7e-863654ae4307/vbnet-syntax-highlighting-in-a-richtextbox-control?forum=vbgeneral)

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    ' Dim 
    Dim brackets As New List(Of String)
    ' AQUA
    brackets.Add("<")
    brackets.Add(">")
    brackets.Add("/>")
    brackets.Add("</")

    Dim tags As New List(Of String)
    ' LIME GREEM
    tags.Add("html")
    tags.Add("title")
    tags.Add("head")

    If RichTextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Dim selectStart As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
        RichTextBox1.Select(0, RichTextBox1.Text.Length)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black
        RichTextBox1.DeselectAll()

        For Each oneWord As String In brackets
            Dim pos As Integer = 0
            Do While RichTextBox1.Text.ToUpper.IndexOf(oneWord.ToUpper, pos) >= 0
                pos = RichTextBox1.Text.ToUpper.IndexOf(oneWord.ToUpper, pos)
                RichTextBox1.Select(pos, oneWord.Length)
                RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua
                pos += 1
            Loop
        Next

        For Each tagWord As String In tags
            Dim pos As Integer = 0
            Do While RichTextBox1.Text.ToUpper.IndexOf(tagWord.ToUpper, pos) >= 0
                pos = RichTextBox1.Text.ToUpper.IndexOf(tagWord.ToUpper, pos)
                RichTextBox1.Select(pos, tagWord.Length)
                RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.LimeGreen
                pos += 1
            Loop
        Next

        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectStart
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not using the " " example, but let's say I wanted that with the < >. Any way to do that?

Comment: It's time to start learning about lexers, parsers, and syntax trees if you want any reasonable sense of accuracy.

Comment: The .NET Compiler Platform (Roslyn) is a good place to start learning about what Joel is talking about.

Comment: Otherwise you could always use the [ScintillaNET library](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).